# Why dosen't querySelector work with getElementById? JS

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, queryselector

Why can't I get any element from getElementById when I try to use querySelector in my code?

```js
let items = document.querySelector('.items');
let item1 = items.getElementById('item1');
let item2 = items.getElementById('item2');

console.log(items, item1, item2)
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div id="item1"></div>
  <div id="item2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't call `getElementById` on an element; it's a method on the `document` object.

Comment: Use querySelectorAll instead and replace with this document.querySelector('div.items');

Comment: let item1 = items.querySelector('#item1');
you can do this too.